# NuGet feed reliability

Tags: nuget

In few projects, that I work on we enabled NuGet packages restoration. We have our own feed for dependencies that are of internal origin, but we as well allow build server to access official NuGet feed to get official packages. It was brought to my attention that this official NuGet feed is external dependency (which it ofc is).
**Question is: how reliable official NuGet feed is in terms of availability?**

I goggled, but no luck.
Thanks in advance
Regards
Kamil

Comment: In our NuGet server [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget), you can have your local feed set up with a connector to the official NuGet feed, which means you can get packages from a single source. On top of that, any packages downloaded from the connected feed will be cached, so even if NuGet server goes down you can still restore your packages from your internal feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been down a few times, once for a few hours. The NuGet team has learned a lot from it, and at least once they were impacted by the general outage of Windows Azure, which of course is out of their hands. Lately, there were no major outages in their service.

In terms of availability, you can trace this through http://status.nuget.org (monthly history at http://status.nuget.org/631950/history).

As with anything external, ensure you have a fallback strategy. NuGet has a local cache: whenever you consume a package it ends up in the local cache, limited to 100 last consumed packages at the moment.

You could also mirror the packages on http://www.myget.org: more info on proxying upstream packages can be found in the docs at http://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/package-sources. Availability of MyGet.org can be traced at http://status.myget.org (and history at http://status.myget.org/519401/history)

Note that MyGet has fallback mechanisms in place to scale out (even to another datacenter), and that you can download your feed as a simple zip-archive at any time as well, if you want to keep a copy on your hard disk somewhere.